# Aspose excel autofitcolumn

Tags: c#, excel, aspose

there is a column, the text is centered and no width is hardcoded during generation of excel.

when excel is generated, the text is overflowed and unable to display entire text.

(such that text width is 20 but default column width is just 10)

in the excel, i can click Home tab > format > Auto Fit Column Width and width is changed to cater the text length.

In order to simulate this AutoFitColumn operation.

I have tried below code, but it doesn't work. (it performed but the column width 't adjusted correctly (column widthshow entire text).

```
                    AutoFitterOptions afo = new AutoFitterOptions();
                    afo.AutoFitMergedCells = true;
                    afo.OnlyAuto = false;
                    ws.AutoFitColumns(col,col,afo);
```

Answer (score 3):

Such issue normally occurs because of fonts. Suppose, your workbook is using some font named ABC but when Aspose.Cells try to auto fit your column, it is unable to find the font named ABC, it then uses some other font e.g. DEF instead of ABC and consequently such issue occurs.

You can find the list of fonts inside your workbook using **Workbook.GetFonts()** methods. You should place all of your fonts in some directory and **set fonts directory** or in case of Windows OS, all of such fonts should be installed by you. For detail, please read these two articles.

- [Get a List of Fonts used in a Spreadsheet or Workbook](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Get+a+List+of+Fonts+used+in+a+Spreadsheet+or+Workbook)
- [Configuring Fonts for Rendering Spreadsheets](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Configuring+Fonts+for+Rendering+Spreadsheets)

Besides, we have tested your code and it works fine. Please see the following sample code, its comments and the screenshot showing the output Excel file generated by it. As you can see, code auto fits the column D fine.

**C#**

```
//Create workbook
Workbook wb = new Workbook();

//Access first worksheet
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

//Set some data in column index 3 which is greater in length than column width.
ws.Cells["D4"].PutValue("This is simple text. This is another.");

//This is your code
int col = 3;
AutoFitterOptions afo = new AutoFitterOptions();
afo.AutoFitMergedCells = true;
afo.OnlyAuto = false;
ws.AutoFitColumns(col, col, afo);

//Save the output Excel file
wb.Save("output.xlsx");
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose